# Story identification: What's the name of this short story about a star-crossed human-alien romance and the robot that reunited them?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Over two decades ago, I read a haunting short story in school, and I can't seem to find any information about it. In summary:

- A young human astronaut on an alien planet falls in love with a young alien woman, possibly a princess.
- The alien woman decides to go with him in his spaceship.
- Due to cryosleep or something, she is frozen with a scared expression on her face. The astronaut thinks he has killed her.
- The astronaut leaves the alien woman on a forested planet, in a sort of Snow White situation. He flies away, heartbroken.
- Surprise! She is actually not dead. She lives out the rest of her life on that planet.
- Years later when they are old and decrepit on their respective worlds, there is a "robot of fate" or "machine of destiny" or something that shows up at the astronaut's house and seemingly kills him by sticking him in the head with a probe. It does the same to the alien woman on her world.
- The machine, its mission completed, lies down on a beautiful planet and disintegrates, leaving in its place two lovers embraced in sleep (it is implied that they are the same two, as young as they were when they met, now able to live the shared life they didn't get to live the first time around).

So yeah, it's really weird. If I had to guess, it would probably be in a grade school literature anthology for young teens. Anyway, I don't know how to find it. I've trawled Reddit and a number of other database websites, and I would love to find it if you have any leads.